# Home work problem that I cant visualize to understand Python Numpy (Newbie)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

New to Numpy and Arrays, my mind is getting bent like warm metal over coals not able to understand how this should work.

I got this homework question that I've been stuck on for days and I have tried understanding it but the better of me I just cant grasp the concept.

**The Question**

```
A 3 by 4 by 4 is created with “arr = np.linspace(1, 48, 48).reshape(3, 4,
4)”. Index or slice this array to obtain the following:
■ 20.0
■ [ 9. 10. 11. 12.]
■ [[33. 34. 35. 36.] [37. 38. 39. 40.] [41. 42. 43. 44.] [45. 46. 47. 48.]]
■ [[5. 6.], [21. 22.] [37. 38.]]
■ [[36. 35.] [40. 39.] [44. 43.] [48. 47.]]
■ [[13. 9. 5. 1.] [29. 25. 21. 17.] [45. 41. 37. 33.]]
■ [[1. 4.] [45. 48.]]
■ [[25. 26. 27. 28.], [29. 30. 31. 32.], [33. 34. 35. 36.], [37. 38. 39. 40.]]
Hint: use flatten and reshape.
```

The documentation they gave us with this question is limited and as a newbie to this is not making sense at all...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Faz

**EDIT***

So I kinda get the concept

```
print("Array range printed for [9. 10. 11. 12.]\n")
print(arr[0:1, 2])

print(
    "\nArray range printed for 20")
print(arr[1, 0, -1])
print(
    "\nArray range printed for [[33. 34. 35. 36.] [37. 38. 39. 40.] [41. 42. 43. 44.] [45. 46. 47. 48.]]\n")
print(arr[2])
```

But I am sitting with this one at the moment

```
print(
    "\nArray range printed for [[5. 6.], [21. 22.] [37. 38.]]\n")
```

How does one print ONLY two digits with a range of 3?

My current solution gives two values but not the 3 ranges

```
print(arr[0:2, 1, 1])
Output = [ 6. 22.]
```

Comment: How does one get [ 9. 10. 11. 12.] with arr = np.linspace(1, 48, 48).reshape(3, 4,
4)? I have tried playing around with the values and see what happens but It is just giving me errors every time...

Comment: I would going into an interactive Python session with `numpy`, preferably `ipython`.  Create `arr` as specified.  `print(arr)` to set it. Then practice doing different kinds of indexing, presumably using information that you've been taught.

Comment: Concerning your edit. The disapointing solution is that you have to print it three times...

Comment: so basically print(arr[0:2, 1, 1],arr[0:2, 3, 2],arr[0:1, 3, 1])  @Yvain ?

Comment: I'm sorry there is indeed a method for this, check out the edit on the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [43]: arr = np.linspace(1, 48, 48).reshape(3, 4, 
    ...: 4)                                                                                                  
In [44]: arr                                                                                                 
Out[44]: 
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
        [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.],
        [ 9., 10., 11., 12.],
        [13., 14., 15., 16.]],

       [[17., 18., 19., 20.],
        [21., 22., 23., 24.],
        [25., 26., 27., 28.],
        [29., 30., 31., 32.]],

       [[33., 34., 35., 36.],
        [37., 38., 39., 40.],
        [41., 42., 43., 44.],
        [45., 46., 47., 48.]]])
```

where is 20?  2nd block, 1st row, 4th column, which translates into:

```
In [45]: arr[1, 0, 3]                                                                                        
Out[45]: 20.0
```

Where's the block that starts with `33,34,...`?  third block?

---

```
[[5. 6.], [21. 22.] [37. 38.]]
```

That's the part of the 2nd row of all blocks

```
a[:,   # all blocks
a[:, 1  # 2nd row
a[:, 1, :2]   # first two entries in each row
```

`[[36. 35.] [40. 39.] [44. 43.] [48. 47.]]` is part of the last block, but with values reversed (.e.g. -1 step size).

`[[13. 9. 5. 1.] [29. 25. 21. 17.] [45. 41. 37. 33.]]` first column, from bottom to top.

`[[1. 4.] [45. 48.]]` - 4 corners; that requires advanced indexing, i.e. with lists of lists or array.  Have they covered that?

`[[25. 26. 27. 28.], [29. 30. 31. 32.], [33. 34. 35. 36.], [37. 38. 39. 40.]]` - rows from different blocks; simple indexing does not work.  But they are contiguous, so with a flattening or reshaping to (12,4) puts them together, from which they can be selected as a simple block.

For all these I am looking at the `Out[44]` display, and identifying where the blocks of numbers occur.  From that I try to describe the selection in terms of blocks, rows, and columns.  The names aren't important to `numpy`, but they help me describe the action(s).

Comment: why are they three values for the linear space function ?

Comment: Did you look up the docs for that function?  start, stop, number of points.  `np.arange(1,49)` would have produced the same thing (except integers).

Comment: No i felt i'd have better ask you. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
Import numpy as np

#print [[36. 35.] [40. 39.] [44. 43.] [48. 47.]]
mask = np.array([3,2]) #mask will swap 3rd and 2nd elements
x = arr[2, :]
print(x[:, mask])

#[[13. 9. 5. 1.] [29. 25. 21. 17.] [45. 41. 37. 33.]]
x = arr[:,:,0] #select all blocks, all rows, first column
mask1 = np.array([0,1,2])

x_t = x.T #Transpose matrix
#mask for manipulating the matrix
mask2 = np.array([3,2,1,0])
print(x_t[:][mask2].T)

# [[1. 4.] [45. 48.]]
mask_blocks = np.array([0,2]) #mask blocks
arr[mask_blocks]

mask_rows = np.array([0,3]) #mask the rows

x = arr[mask_blocks][:, mask_rows] #index/slice the matrix
mask_index = np.array([0,3]) #mask for indexes

#x[:][0,0][mask_index] gets the first values
#x[:][1,1][mask_index] gets the second values

print(np.array([x[:][0,0][mask_index], x[:][1,1][mask_index]])) #print [[ 1.  4.][45. 48.]]

#[[25. 26. 27. 28.], [29. 30. 31. 32.], [33. 34. 35. 36.], [37. 38. 39. 40.]]

mask_blocks = np.array([1,2])

x = arr[mask_blocks] #gets the columns
x
mask_rows = np.array([2,3]) #mask the rows

x = arr[mask_blocks][:, mask_rows] #index/slice the matrix

mask_index = np.array([0,3]) #mask for indexes

#arr[1][2:4,:] gets second block, last two rows
#arr[2][0:2,:] gets third block, first two rows

print(np.array([arr[1][2:4,:], arr[2][0:2,:]]).reshape(4,4).tolist()) #prints list
```